# Upper and lower period for WaveletComp::analyze.wavelet

Tags: r, wavelet, wavelet-transform

I would like to perform a wavelet analysis on No2 data. I have data only for five months, collected every minute. Can someone help me determine the lower and upper periods to use for [analyze.wavelet](https://cran.r-project.org/package=WaveletComp)?

this is how my code looks at the moment:

```
library(WaveletComp)

wave <- analyze.wavelet (my.data = Messbox[,c("date", "no2")], 
        my series = "no2", 
        loess.span = 0.75, 
        dt = 1, 
        dj = 1/length(Messbox$no2), 
        lowerPeriod = 1, 
        upperPeriod = 288, 
        make.pval = T, 
        method = "white.noise", 
        n.sim  = 100, 
        date.format = "%Y-%m-%d", 
        date.tz = "UTC", 
        verbose = T)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You maximize your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  may help.